# How to replace the information inside a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace one div with another when I click on it using jQuery but I can't do it, I don't know if I need to use the hide attribute on one div.

this is the code

```
<div id="prepersonal">this is a test 1</div>
<div id="personal">this is a test 2</div>
```

and this is the css

```
#prepersonal {
   width: 330px;
   height: 330px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #FF6801;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: Tahoma;
   padding-top:7px; 
}

#personal {
   width: 330px;
   height: 330px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #FF6801;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: Tahoma;
   padding-top:7px;
}
```

Can somebody know the answer?

Comment: What is your javascript?

Comment: This is unclear, remove as in remove and insert another div. Or hide one of your divs?

Comment: What `div` do you need to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following replaces the content *inside* one `div` with the content of the one that was `click`ed:

```
$(function(){
    $('#prepersonal').on('click', function(){
        $('#personal').html(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

---

**After your comment:**

```
$(function(){
    var a = $('#prepersonal'), b = $('#personal');

    // you can remove this call to hide by initially
    // hiding the div using display:none; in CSS
    b.hide();

    a.on('click', function(){
        toggledivs();
    });
    b.on('click', function(){
        toggledivs();
    });

    function toggledivs(){
        a.toggle();
        b.toggle();  
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f6r82/

Comment: the personal div must be hided and when you click on prepersonal, hide prepersonal and show personal

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#prepersonal").click(function(){
        $("#personal").html($("#prepersonal").html()); //You can use the text() method instead of html if you need only the text
        $("prepersonal").css("display", "none");
    });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('#prepersonal').on('click', function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($('#personal'));
});
});
```